# Grab last price of the day from other dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two dataframes:

Dataframe 'prices' contains minute pricing.

```
ts                          average
2017-12-13 15:55:00-05:00   339.389
2017-12-13 15:56:00-05:00   339.293
2017-12-13 15:57:00-05:00   339.172
2017-12-13 15:58:00-05:00   339.148
2017-12-13 15:59:00-05:00   339.144
```

Dataframe 'articles' contains articles:

```
ts                          title
2017-10-25 11:45:00-04:00   Your Evening Briefing
2017-11-24 14:15:00-05:00   Tesla's Grand Designs Distract From Model 3 Bo...
2017-10-26 11:09:00-04:00   UAW Files Claim That Tesla Fired Workers Who S...
2017-10-25 11:42:00-04:00   Forget the Grid of the Future, Puerto Ricans J...
2017-10-22 09:54:00-04:00   Tesla Reaches Deal for Shanghai Facility, WSJ ...
```

When 'article' happens, I want the current average stock price (easy), plus the stock price of the end of the day (problem).

My current approach:

```
articles['t-eod'] = prices.loc[articles.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[0]].between_time('15:30','15:31')
```

However, it gives a warning:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Reading the docs didn't make it a lot clearer to me.

So question: How can I, for every Article, get Prices' last average price of that day?

Thanks!

/Maurice

Comment: Dont you need a `join`  between the dataframe to know which price belongs to which article ?

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt thanks. Afaik: no not needed. If I put ```articles['t-0'] = prices['average']``` it shows current price for that time.

Comment: As per my understanding, `prices['average']` should give you the whole series.  Now for `articles['t-eod']` you wish to have the average price for when that article was added. Basically check what date it is and find the average of that date and enter it on `t-eod`. Am I correct ?

Comment: Almost yes, thanks. The average price per minute, I've got. I would like to grab the last average minute price of that day. That's the EndOfDay (eod) price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `idxmax` on `ts` to identify the index of the maximum timestamp of that date and extract the average value with loc

```
#Reset our index
prices_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
articles_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Ensure our ts field is datetime
prices_df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(prices_df['ts'])
articles_df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(articles_df['ts'])

#Get maximum average value from price_df by date
df_max = prices_df.loc[prices_df.groupby(prices_df.ts.dt.date, as_index=False).ts.idxmax()]

#We need to join df_max and articles on the date so we make a new index
df_max['date'] = df_max.ts.dt.date
articles_df['date'] = articles_df.ts.dt.date
df_max.set_index('date',inplace=True)
articles_df.set_index('date',inplace=True)

#Set our max field
articles_df['max'] = df_max['average']
articles_df.set_index('ts',inplace=True)
```